# vertical spacing of ul elements using only inline code

Tags: html, html-email

I'm new to this. I'm writing an email template using HTML. I'm not sure if CSS is supported, but I know everything has to be inline. I have one line of space between my paragraphs, using `<br />`. I also have a ul element, and I want the same spacing between the list items.

When I use `<br />`, I end up with two lines of space. From reading other questions, I'm thinking I need to use `span style` or `div style` to change the bottom margin or line height, but I don't know what that should look like exactly.

Comment: Can you add some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by set line-height property to your ul element like this.

```html
<p>First line of text <br/> <br/> Second line of text</p>
<ul style="line-height:2em">
<li>First li element</li>
<li>Second li element</li>
<li>Third li element</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does your answer use CSS? I tried what you said and the editor auto-deleted the style part. Back to <ul>. It deletes things a lot. I'd like to figure out rules for what is supported and what isn't.

Comment: I found out that the editor is called CKEditor 4. I tried looking at the documentation to see what is supported, but it's pretty confusing to me. Here's the link: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/styles.html#style-rules

Answer (score 0):

Because the editor can't support CSS and even auto-deletes some HTML things, my eventual work-around was to create three separate lists.

```html
<ul>
    <li><span style="font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:12pt">Text of first list item.</span></span></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><span style="font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:12pt">Text of second list item.</span></span></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><span style="font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:12pt">Text of third list item.</span></span></li>
</ul>
```